# (Re) name Spring Boot HealthIndicator

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I've got the following [HealthIndicator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthIndicator.html):

```
@Component
public class FooBarHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {
  // ...
```

Which, **on production**, results in a JSON like:

```
status "DOWN"
  details
    fooBar
      status "DOWN"
```

But in my integration test the JSON looks like

```
status "DOWN"
  details
    com.acme.fooBar
      status "DOWN"
```

Note the package path.

So my question is: Who's responsible for naming HealthIndicators within the `/health` JSON? And (how) can I configure this?

PS: I already passed a name to `@Component`:

```
@Component("fooBar") // name clash!!
public class FooBarHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {
  // ...
```

which did the trick, but as `FooBarHealthIndicator` monitors a class `FooBar`, a bean of that name already is present. However, as it works in production without naming the `HealthIndicator`, there must be an additional way...

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE**: This approach relies on exploitation of an internal implementation, which may change in the future. You have been warned.

The class responsible for naming the health indicator is called `HealthIndicatorNameFactory` and looks like this in Spring Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE:

```
public class HealthIndicatorNameFactory implements Function<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String apply(String name) {
        int index = name.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).indexOf("healthindicator");
        if (index > 0) {
            return name.substring(0, index);
        }
        return name;
    }

}
```

This means that if you name your `@Component` to (say) `@Component("fooBarHealthIndicator")` you should be able to get by without any bean name clashes. The name clash occurs when Spring is wiring up your beans, not by the Actuator itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the bean for your health indicator via a configuration class and set via name of your health indicator via the `@Bean` annotation, as shown  below.

```java
@Configuration
public class HealthIndicatorConfiguration {
    @Bean("MyServiceIndicator")
    public HealthIndicator healthIndicatorForMyService() {
        return new MyHealthIndicator();
    }
}
```